# How to show images in autocomplete

Tags: material-ui

I'd like to have an image in the autocomplete text dataSource. Do you know how to do that?

I saw the doc, it puts MenuItem in the value, but I need the value to perform some search, so I can't change it.

Answer (score 1):

```
<AutoComplete
  ...
  dataSource={companies}
/>

const companies = [{
  text: "Google"
  value: 
    (<MenuItem>
      <img src="../images/google-logo.png" />
      <span>Google</span>
    </MenuItem>)
}, {
  ...
}]
```

Is this solution good enough for you?

Comment: Ok, but why do I need to change the value? When I select it how can I get the value to send in my API ?